# Generate styles using LESS recursive function and media queries

Tags: css, less

I am trying to generate some relative to screen height and decided to try to use LESS to generate something like that, even if a bit heavy just as a test:

```
@baseHeight: 1px;
.setRelativeHeight(@screenHeight, @minHeightDiff, @maxHeightDiff) when(@screenHeight < 2400) {

    @media (min-height: @baseHeight * @screenHeight) {
        min-height: @baseHeight * (@screenHeight - @minHeightDiff);
        max-height: @baseHeight * (@screenHeight - @maxHeightDiff);
    }
    .setRelativeHeight(@screenHeight + 20, @minHeightDiff, @maxHeightDiff);
}
```

That seems to work, most of it, but this is part of what it generates when calling it:

```
@media not all {
#ConversationMessages .messages {
    max-height: 2100px;
    min-height: 2000px;
}
}
@media not all {
#ConversationMessages .messages {
    max-height: 2120px;
    min-height: 2020px;
}
}
@media not all {
#ConversationMessages .messages {
    max-height: 2140px;
    min-height: 2040px;
}
}
@media not all {
#ConversationMessages .messages {
    max-height: 2160px;
    min-height: 2060px;
}
}
```

So the styles are being set properly but the media condition is lost :( Does anyone know why? :)

Thanks!!

**Update**
Fixed adding parenthesis to the media condition (see comment below).

Comment: Arithmetic operations inside `@media` queries should always be in parens regardless of [--strict-math](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-math) option. I.e. should be `@media (min-height: (@baseHeight * @screenHeight)) ...`. Although speaking of your initial result, what Less compiler do you use? It does not seem like a result the [reference Less implementation](http://lesscss.org/) would generate in this case.

Comment: Thanks! It works! I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with a template that comes with bootstrap and LESS already installed, checking the NuGet packages I think it's "BundleTransformer.Less".

Comment: I see, most likely it's `dotless`, so just in case be careful as `dotless` is quite outdated  Less implementation and not every Less example you'll find works there. (Good to know this media query thing works the same way there too).

Comment: @Ruben.Canton please add your own answer (and accept that) instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arithmetic operations inside `@media` queries should always be in parens regardless of [`--strict-math`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-math) option. I.e. should be `@media (min-height: (@baseHeight * @screenHeight))`.