# LESS addition operator (+) is appending instead of adding

Tags: css, less, gulp

I'm having a strange issue I haven't seen occur. I am trying to do some basic addition to some variables like this:

```
@screen-break-sm:       768px;
@screen-break-md:       992px;

@screen-max-mobile:     @screen-break-sm;
@screen-min-desktop:    @screen-break-sm + 1;
```

Then, those values are being used in some media queries. When it is compiled using `gulp-less` (version ~3.0.0 in package.json) via Gulp, the output ends up being something like:

```
@media (min-width:768px + 1) {
   // CSS
}
```

I'm expecting:

```
@media (min-width:769px) {
   // CSS
}
```

I have tried doing the addition as both `@screen-break-sm + 1` and also `screen-break-sm + 1px`. I've also tried removing the `px` part of the original values and doing the add and appending the `px` afterwards, but that doesn't add either.

In case it is relevant, this is one of the gulp scripts that builds a section where I first ran into this issue:

```
module.exports = function (build) {
    return function () {

        var pagesPath = build.options.styles.buildPath + '/pages/';

        return build.gulp.src('./resources/assets/less/pages/**/*')
            .pipe(build.plugins.less({
                paths: [ build.plugins.path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'vendor', 'theme', 'bootstrap') ]
            })).on('error', build.errorHandler)
            .pipe(build.plugins.minifyCss()).on('error', build.errorHandler)
            .pipe(build.plugins.extReplace('.min.css')).on('error', build.errorHandler)
            .pipe(build.gulp.dest(pagesPath));
    };
};
```

Any ideas why LESS is concatenating/appending instead of performing addition?

[EDIT]

While the solution is the same as the other question that was identified as a possible duplicate, that question does not discuss the problem that users will encounter directly, and therefore I think this question is much better suited for searching purposes. I never found that solution after an hour of Googling and only after getting the answer and the "strict math" verbiage did that other question show up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate styles using LESS recursive function and media queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241544/generate-styles-using-less-recursive-function-and-media-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [strict math option](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-options) which default value is OFF. Are you sure that for some reason you don't have it set to ON?

```
lessc -sm=on
lessc --strict-math=on
```

Comment: I'm not using the CLI transpiler directly -- I'm using the gulp-less plugin in gulp (https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less). When I type `lessc` in Ubuntu, I get the message it isn't installed and offers help to install it. Maybe I can figure out how to explicitly turn it off in the options.

Comment: I tried both on and off (true/false) variations as described here: http://java-hackers.com/p/christophehurpeau/gulp-less and it didn't change anything. But as it turns out, I think your answer is still correct. I changed my code to `(@screen-break-sm + 1)` with the added parenthesis and it worked as described in the documentation you linked to: `With strict math on, only maths that is inside un-necessary parenthesis will be processed. `. Thanks!